# hide and show button in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am making a tile related game in unity 3d where player jumps on the right tile and I am also making hint button so that player uses those hints but the issue is I want to hide and show button when player jumps on the first tile and when my player moves onto the next tile it will disable my button and show another button.

I have tried canvas group and sorting layer but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried using `btn.gameObject.SetActive(false)` and vice versa?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, it looks like you would need to put an new game object on top of the tiles to act as a collider.
You can then call button game object enable/disable within the native trigger enter/stay/leave functions (Add these functions within a script attached to your created collider) e.g.:

```
// change these functions to 3D equivalent if project is 3D
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "myplayertag")
        {
            myButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "myplayertag")
        {
            myButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
     {
         if (col.tag == "myplayertag")
         {
             myButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         }
     }
```

Make sure to mark said collider object as trigger like so:
[image: Screenshot]